# Combine Struts 2 and Dojo tags

Tags: jsp, struts2, dojo

I have a problem with tags of Struts and Dojo when I combine them like:

```
<sx:a href="modifUser?droit=<s:property value="libelle"/>&user_name=dd">Link</sx:a>
```

I have this error:

```
/editUser.jsp (line: 56, column: 63) Symbole égal (equal) attendu
```

Comment: You can't nest tags like that, it's not valid JSP. Assuming you just haven't read the stack overflow formatting documentation. Use OGNL. Also note the dojo tags have been deprecated for *years*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest tags in struts tags' attributes, but you can use OGNL expressions there. Struts2 Dojo plugin is deprecated, so you have an opportunity to use [Struts2 jQuery plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/S2PLUGINS/jQuery+plugin+-+Easy+AJAX+and+Widget+Integration).

```
<sj:a href="modifUser?droit=%{libelle}&user_name=dd">Link</sj:a>
```